# Simulink Real-Time Library linux

Tags: linux, matlab, udp, real-time, simulink

I'm trying to work with a co-simulator that communicates with Simulink using UDP packets. The problem is that in my Matlab installation I can't find the necessary library (Simulink real-time). 
I read carefully each Matlab components during the installation but on Linux that library isn't present, on windows instead there is.

[image: Simulink schema]

The missing block is this one [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/xpc/io_ref/bytepacking.html?searchHighlight=Byte%20Packing&s_tid=doc_srchtitle). Is there an alternative for that block available also for linux or where can I find this library?

Thanks

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: `Simulink Real-Time` is a Windows only product.